# Add a new column in text file

Tags: python, numpy

I have already searched in the site but did not find anything specific for my case.
I have a code that creates an array from a text file, and I just want to create a new file like the input one, but with the new array added in a column on the right. How can I do?

Example of input file:

```
4.00171 2.04336E14 14.31034 0.65049
2.56491 6.89220E13 13.83835 1.05022
1.95019 3.45559E13 13.53852 1.38901
```

A part of code that creates an array:

```
import numpy as np

dataset = np.genfromtxt(fname='input.dat') 
s=dataset[:,3]
d=1.686/s
```

And I just want to add the array d to a column on the right of the input file and save all in a new output file. (I'm using python 2.7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do a `concatenate` along the proper axis?

The problem is that your variables `d` and `s` both have the shape `(3,)` and thus are more of a vector than an array. The following solves the problem:

```
s=dataset[:,3]
d=1.686/s
d=d[:,None]
output = np.concatenate((dataset,d), axis=1)
```

Now you just need to output your data back into a file and you're done...

`np.savetxt('example.txt', output)`

Comment: The output file has a has a different format than input, but it works! Thank you!
A tip for the format?

Comment: To get the same output format as before, you'll have to change the last line to `np.savetxt('example.txt', output, delimiter=" ", fmt="%.5f %.5E %.5f %.5f %.5f")`. Best to read up on the formating [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

Answer (score 2):

With `numpy.append` and `numpy.savetxt` functions:

```
dataset = np.genfromtxt('input.dat')
d = 1.686/dataset[:,3]
d = np.reshape(d, (dataset.shape[0],1))   # adjust dimension of the new array
result = np.append(dataset, d, 1)         # append as last column
np.savetxt('output.txt', result, delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")
```

---

`output.txt` contents would look like:

```
4.00171 2.04336e+14 14.31034 0.65049 2.59189226583
2.56491 6.8922e+13 13.83835 1.05022 1.60537792082
1.95019 3.45559e+13 13.53852 1.38901 1.21381415541
```

Comment: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 9 into shape (3,1)`...
What's the meaning of np.reshape(d, (3,1))?

Comment: `np.reshape(d, (3,1))` will reshape the array `d` to dimension: 3 rows, 1 column. Actually, I've tested on Python 3.5

Comment: ok, but i write only a part of input file... the number of rows can change

Comment: @AlessandroPeca, ok, you got my update for multiple rows

Answer (score 1):

Read the file into an array of lines by splitting on the newline character.  Loop through the lines.  After writing each line to the new file append the next element of your "d" array (plus a newline).

Answer (score 0):

In order to open a file and and save it as another one you should use `with open` .

Try this:

```
import os
# dirpath is the path to your file
# file is the name of your file with extension
# Read the file and store it in a variable
with open(os.path.join(dirpath, file), 'r') as f:
    filedata = f.read()

# Manipulate your filedata here

# Write the file out again to a new file
with open(os.path.join(dirpath, new_file), 'w') as f:
    f.write(filedata)
```

If you want a good way to manipulate your data I would suggest using the [Pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

A full example using `Pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dirpath = r'C:\Users\eandrade_brp\Desktop'
file = 'input_example'
new_file = 'new.data'

dataset = np.genfromtxt(fname=os.path.join(dirpath, file))
s = dataset[:, 3]
d = 1.686 / s

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)    # Create DataFrame from matrix
df['4'] = d   # Add new column

# Save it to a new file without head, index and with white space separator
df.to_csv(os.path.join(dirpath, new_file), header = False, index=False,  sep=' ')
```

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question.

Comment: His questions could be separated in two parts. The first on how to open a file and save as another one. The second is how to add a column to the data that he read. I answered the first and suggested how to do the second. Now I edited with the code for doing both